# Consuming webhooks shopify-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, shopify, webhooks

I'm in the process of building my first RoR webapp and I'm currently trying to set up an integration with Shopify. I want to create an order in my web application whenever one is created in Shopify. For this I want to use a Shopify webhook. Step two will be to set it up so that after processing the order I'll use the Shopify API to update some records. For now my main concern is receiving the webhooks. I've been looking at the documentation for the Shopify gem but with my limited RoR skills I can't seem to figure it out. I've been searching the web for a few hours but can't find any clear examples / explanation.

I'm confused about this gem; shopify-api (https://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/using-api-gem-with-private-app-credentials). I've created a private app in shopify, but after that I'm lost. Where am I supposed to place this code and how is this invoked after receiving a webhook?

It seems to me that this gem is mainly used to access the Shopify API instead of consuming webhooks. Am I going at this all wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For receiving the changes (especially `Order Creation` event) from Shopify, you don't need to use any gem or third party to integrate!

Here are the steps that I did before in my app:

**1. Provide an api in your app to receive a webhook event**

Here is an example:

Your route:

```
post '/shopify/create_order', to: 'shopify#create_order'
```

Your controller:

```
class ShopifyController < ApplicationController
  def create_order
    # process shopify order here: all info in `params`
  end
end
```

**2. Config to call webhook from your [Shopify Settings](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/settings/notifications/webhooks).** The configured url will be:

```
http://your_production_url/shopify/create_order
```

If you want to test from localhost, go to `step 3`

**3. (Optional) Test from your localhost**

Download this free tool: [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and extract it to your machine.
Run ngrok in your terminal to generate a forwarding url to your localhost by this command:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

So you will get the output from console like this:

[image]

Copy the generated url (http://fbc5cf88.ngrok.io for example) above and add to your Shopify settings in step 2

**4. (Optional but critical) Set privacy in your app**, to make sure only Shopify can call your api. Follow this [documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks#verify-webhook)

Shopify also provides api to integrate with Shopify resources: create/update `product`, `collection`, `collect`, `metafield`,... You can directly use it. All was described at [Shopify API documentation](https://docs.shopify.com/api/product). But the easiest way to work with Shopify is [shopify_api](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_api) gem which provides an interface to work with Shopify (via `ActiceResource`)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. This cleared things up for me. I found this piece of code that could be used to validate webhooks: https://github.com/csaunders/shopProductSink/blob/038e8c3f76e96e8c12d0b1c14d1c32a48c679907/app/models/shop_product_sink/webhooks.rb

If I create a model for this code, how do I use/include it in my orders controller? I am currently receiving webhooks on my staging environment and the orders are created succesfully, but they aren't authenticated so anyone can create orders.

Comment: Cheers, I just got the authentication to work. Thanks for the pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Probably reading up on the [documentation on Webhooks](https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks) would help you figure out a lot of what you need to do

In essence, here are the overview of what you need to start consuming web hooks:

**1. Create your web hooks**

- You can do it using the Shopify API ([`POST /admin/webhooks.json`](https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhook#create))
- Or you can do it through [store admin](https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks#through-store-admin)

The params that you need to take note of:

- topic: the type of hook you want (for e.g `orders/create`)
- address: the URL of the endpoint that you would be consuming the hook at (for e.g: `https://myapp.domain.com/hooks/order_create`)

**2. Create your endpoint that will respond to hooks**

- You then need to setup your ROR app to expose an endpoint that will respond to a POST request.
- This endpoint is the same URL that you previously specified when creating the hook
  More info at https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks#respond-to-webhook

**Notes:** You also need to implement a way to verify that requests that you receive through the endpoints came from Shopify, [detailed here.](https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks#verify-webhook)

Comment: Thanks mate, definitely helpful

Comment: Cheers, I just got the authentication to work. Thanks for the pointers!